# Chatbot Visual Dialog Editor

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot

We did some research on Azure Bot Framework and we found out that we need to use code to build our Chatbot dialog.

Does Microsoft or any of their Partners has something similar to IBM Watson Asssitant's visual dialog editor?
Screencap: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-assistant/assets/img/image_1.png

The visual dialog editor is very easy to use to create complex dialogues for their chatbot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the "partners", but for now, Microsoft does not have a visual editor.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is currently under investigation with the Bot Framework team. There is no ETA at this time, so I would recommend staying update-to-date on new feature announcements. Some places to track news are the Bot Framework [Blogs](https://blog.botframework.com/), [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), and GitHub [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/botframework-sdk).

Alternatively, you can look at [Conversation Learner](https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-conversation-learner) as an option. As they state,

> Project Conversation Learner enables you to build and teach conversational interfaces that learn from example interactions. Unlike traditional approaches, Project Conversation Learner considers the end-to-end context of a dialogue to help improve responses and deliver more compelling user experiences.

It is experimental and closed to the general public, however you can request an invitation (follow the above link) to join the project.

Hope of help!